# How to show the variable in a input field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and i want to update the values of the table cell on click .
I want to show an input field containing current value .
Current value is showing but when i click on input filed to edit then suddenly the input field become empty .

```
$('td#11').click(function(event){
 var valuee = $('td#11').text();
 $('td#11').html("<form method='post'><input style='color:black;' value=" +valuee+ "></form>");

});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An alternative other solutions:**

```
$('td#11').click(function(event){
if($('td#11').find('form, input').length == 0) { 
    var valuee = $('td#11').text();
    $('td#11').html("<form method='post'><input id='txt11' style='color:black;' value=" +valuee+ "></form>");
}
});
```

You can add another snippet with above snippet to remove text-box on losing focus to it as below:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input#txt11', function() {
    $('td#11').html($('input#txt11').val());
});
```

**Working demo**
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adwxvmpt/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your click event fires again and again and so on.

To avoíd this, use `event.target.tagName` And check if it does not match "INPUT"

```js
$('td#11').click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName != "INPUT") {

    var valuee = $('td#11').text();
    $('td#11').html("<form method='post'><input style='color:black;' value=" + valuee + "></form>");

  }
});
```

**Working Demo below**

```js
$('td#11').click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName != "INPUT") {

    var valuee = $('td#11').text();
    $('td#11').html("<form method='post'><input style='color:black;' value=" + valuee + "></form>");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="11">text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```